# how do I find the most common words unix

Tags: unix

I have a text file and I want to find the most common pairs of words in it.
I found the command:

```
tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' < test.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -10
```

which gives me a list with the most 10 common words.
I need to replace it with pairs of words.

Comment: Can you show example input and output? With input of two lines, `a b a` and `b a`, what is the desired result for `a b`: once or twice?

Comment: for example, for the text a b c d a b d d e
the result should be: a b

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`tr  '[:space:]' '[\n*]' < file_name | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr -k1 |  head`

In your command, you are replacing character with the new line instead of spaces.